# how to install wkhtmltopdf on xampp?

Tags: php, installation, xampp, wkhtmltopdf

i'd like to install wkhtmltopdf on my xampp system and use it under php.
any ideas how to do it - is there any tutorial? :/
i've run the wkhtmltox-0.10.0_rc2-installer.exe but it seems like it didn't change anything on my local xampp system.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer extracts the executable under `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\` per default - or whatever you specified.

To use it from within PHP just supply the absolute path:

```
exec("c:/programs/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe www.site.com pdf.pdf");
```

Or move the .exe where it's easier accessible. (Should you care about making things simpler.)